# csv data ending with comma at end | python |

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have written a code but the issue with the code is

I am not able to identify how to get rid of last ending command comma from my obtained expected output

**Code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_data='''
<job_details>
    <role>
        <name>Vikas</name>
        <salary>$5.95</salary>
        <job_description>Developer</job_description>
    </role>
    <role>
        <name>Dip</name>
        <salary>$7.95</salary>
        <job_description>Backend Developer</job_description>
    </role>
</job_details>
'''

get_root_element = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
cnt=0
for i in range(len(list(get_root_element))):
  for x in get_root_element[i]:
    print(x.text,end=",")
    cnt=cnt + 1
    if cnt == len(list(get_root_element[1])):
      break
  print()
```

**Expected output :**

```
Vikas,$5.95,Developer,
Dip,$7.95,Backend Developer,
```

Comment: Separate the print of result `x.text` and using `end=','` only for element but not the last?

Comment: @dudung : Not getting what actually need to do ? Can you elaborate

Comment: See my answer. One more question, what do you want to do with it? Wouldn't it make more sense to have like a DataFrame with the columns `["name", "salary", "job_description"]` instead of all details joined together to one string ? You would have easier access to it later on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your code with this:

You can iterate directly through `get_root_Elements`.
Then instead of using `print()` you take all elements of each item and `join` it with the right seperator.
Also no need to break out of the for loop, it will stop itself.
I appended all results to a list `out`, where you have 2 strings seperated by `,`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_data='''
<job_details>
    <role>
        <name>Vikas</name>
        <salary>$5.95</salary>
        <job_description>Developer</job_description>
    </role>
    <role>
        <name>Dip</name>
        <salary>$7.95</salary>
        <job_description>Backend Developer</job_description>
    </role>
</job_details>
'''

get_root_element = ET.fromstring(xml_data)

out = []
for item in get_root_element:
    res = ','.join(x.text for x in item)
    out.append(res)

print(out) 
['Vikas,$5.95,Developer', 'Dip,$7.95,Backend Developer']
```

As I said, your code has some basic "mistakes". A for loop will stop itself at the moment it iterated through all elements. There is no need to define a count and check when count equals the len of your iterator. If you still want to know how to manage it with this `print` statement, you could loop through all elements except the last one and print it with the `end` statement. The last one gets printed separately without `end`. Still, I wouldn't recommend it.

```
for i in range(len(list(get_root_element))):
    for x in get_root_element[i][:-1]:
        print(x.text,end=",")
    print(get_root_element[i][-1].text)

Vikas,$5.95,Developer
Dip,$7.95,Backend Developer
```

Comment: Can you tell me how i need to modify my existing code to get the same output as you are getting from your code... I like your code but need to know how to obtain from my code as well ... need to get rid of last comma

Answer (score 1):

Editing your code, here's a suggested solution:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_data='''
<job_details>
    <role>
        <name>Vikas</name>
        <salary>$5.95</salary>
        <job_description>Developer</job_description>
    </role>
    <role>
        <name>Dip</name>
        <salary>$7.95</salary>
        <job_description>Backend Developer</job_description>
    </role>
</job_details>
'''

get_root_element = ET.fromstring(xml_data)

result = []
for i in range(len(list(get_root_element))):
    temp = []
    for x in get_root_element[i]:
        temp.append(x.text)
    temp_str = ','.join(temp)
    result.append(temp_str)

print(result)
```

Output

```
['Vikas,$5.95,Developer', 'Dip,$7.95,Backend Developer']
```

But I must say @Rabinzel has a much neater solution!